# How can I incorporate entitlements with over 50,000 data points in SSRS Report?

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

In my SSRS report I am attempting to incorporate entitlements. If a user puts a specific person ID in the parameter, I'd like to be able to compare it against the up to 50,000 ids they are entitled to use and to put up an error message if not.

The available values feature only allows me to use a dropdown, which is incovenient for so many ids. What are my options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A drop down would be very inconvenient for that many choices. Is it possible to break them down by a category or something like that? You could then create cascading parameters to make the list easier to deal with.

Otherwise it would have to be a free text field. Depending on the complexity of the report contents you could handle it a couple of ways.

If it is a very simple report with just a tablix you can set the no data row value to your error message.

If it is more complex you can display the error message using two rectangles. The first one would simply contain a text box with the error message in it. Then put the actual report comments in the second box. Control the visibility of these rectangles based on an expression that checks the number of rows returned by the dataset or some other indication that the input was invalid. You may even need to create a second dataset to check for input validity if there isn't a reliable way to use your normal query.